# Multiple pages in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to make multiple pages in react app , and I'm confused how to set my codes properly;I have a component folder which has Navbar.jsx which I have my nav items that i want to send me to another page when i click(react-route) . and I have the Container folder which has Header.jsx and that what i want to change based on the nav items clicked.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { RiMenu3Line, RiCloseLine } from 'react-icons/ri';
import './Navbar.css';
import logo from '../../assets/logo.png'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link,
    useRouteMatch,
    useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

const Menu = () => (
    <>
        <Router>
            <p><Link to={"/about"}>About</Link></p>
            <p><Link to={"/contact"}>Contact</Link></p>

        </Router>
    </>
)
const Navbar = () => {
...
```

Header.jsx I didnt change any thing

```
const Header = () => {
    return (...
```

Comment: You need to define routes, not only links ;) you should start with the react-router tutorial which is kind of useful > https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Comment: @JiaSH Thank u !